# How to get background color of button

Tags: android

I want to get the background color of button.
As suggested in many solutions I have tried following code

```
Button button = HostActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.<ButtonId>);
        ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable)button.getBackground();
           return( viewColor.getColor());
```

But on this I am getting Exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried following Code

```
View view = currentActivity.findViewById(idNumber);

        ColorStateList colorStateList = view.getBackgroundTintList();

        int defaultColor = colorStateList.getColorForState(
                new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled},0);
           return(defaultColor);
}
```

It has resolved the issue. This function returns background color of View.